# Reshape columns of matrix into multidimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, bigdata, reshape

I have solar data in a huge (17GB) matrix, call it A. Each column represents one station that collected the one-second data over the year and a half period. The stations are physically in a grid format on the ground and correspond (roughly) to the column numbers. I represented the layout using station numbers in a 9x9 matrix (call it B) like this:

```
38     0    40     0    42     0    44     0    49
 0    28     0     0    30     0     0    33     0
37     0     5    10    15    20    25     0    48
 0     0     4     9    14    19    24     0     0
36    27     3     8    13    18    23    32    47
 0     0     2     7    12    17    22     0     0
35     0     1     6    11    16    21     0    46
 0    26     0     0    29     0     0    31     0
34     0    39     0    41     0    43     0    45
```

The zeros are blank spots. Now, I'd like to represent each row in my huge matrix, A, as one slice of a new multidimensional matrix (call it NewMat), with the columns of A being "mapped" onto the 9x9 matrix above.

I have the following in a loop:

```
for mm = 1:length(A) % rows

    for i = 1:length(HeaderStatNums) % column headers

        [j k] = find(B == HeaderStatNums(i));

        NewMat(j,k,mm) = A(mm,i+1); % This maps to the new matrix. (The i+1 is just 
                                    %  a shift
    end
end
```

This works, but due to the size of my original matrix I cannot create a copy of A in NewMat without running out of memory. I have 16GB physical and about 15GB virtual. Thus, I can only copy portions of A into NewMat. One solution would be to load and unload the MAT file where the matrix is stored, but that's clunky. Any ideas?

Comment: If you elaborate a bit more on what type of mapping you want to carry out we might help you, but as is the only way is processing data in blocks. Otherwise, it seems you are trying a very inefficient approach.

Comment: A few comments on the code: 1) You should preallocate NewMat instead of growing in the loop. 2) You could try using a sparse matrix for NewMat since it looks like there will be many unused elements based on the `B` matrix. 3) You can swap the inner and outer loops and then just call `find` in the outer loop. 4) Once you swap the loops, you can probably just do a matrix assignment instead of the inner loop.

Comment: What is the reason you want such mapping: to simplify some calculations with your data or to arrange the data in easy-to-understand manner? For the former I agree with Oleg. The latter can be achieved in more efficient way without copying the data.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @ Oleg,anandr: The "mapping" is simply a reshape where column 2 in matrix A will always point to NewMat(6,3,:); column 3 will point to NewMat(5,3,:), etc. The reason for this is to generate one-second snapshots of solar data over a given area. I'd like to "stack" the NewMat as images for a movie. @shoelzer: I do preallocate the NewMat, but I just didn't add that to the above code. The sparse matrix is a good idea, I'll try that out. Eventually, I'll be using knnsearch to fill in the gaps. I'll also swap the loops to see if that has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments on the question says that the reason for all of this is to generate frames of a movie. Since that is the goal, I can think of a couple different options:

1. Generate a movie for some limited time span instead of the entire time span of your data set. That will use less memory.
2. Write each frame's data to a file as you loop, but don't keep frames in memory. Then you can use another function to load and show the frames. That way you won't ever have two copies of the data in memory at once.